# Jquery append to (dynamic by id)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say i have function with id paremeter and two select box

```
<select id="one" onchange="Fill(2)"></select>
<select id="two" onchange="Fill(3)"></select>
<select id="three"></select>
```

My function

```
function Fill(id){  
//some manupulation
$('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo('#two');
}
```

But instead of doing many

```
if(id==2) {$('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo('#two');}
if(id==3) {$('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo('#three');}
```

i want something like

```
$('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo(DYNAMIC);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, hence the comment, but it looks like you just want to append the new `option` to the currently-changed element? So...wouldn't `$('<option />').val(/*..*/).html(/*..*/).appendTo($(this));` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make it much easier by using ids such as `select-1`, `select-2` etc. and then use `'#select-' + id`.

Otherwise you need a mapping object which maps from digits to spelled numbers.

Comment: WOW i didn`t know that i can do that like this! I was thinking that it should would work like this, but didn`t tried. I made 200 lines jquery function but i didnt know this :))))

Answer (score 2):

```
function Fill(id){  
  var index = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three'; 
  };
  $('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo('#' + index[id]);
  // or just, but in this case you need to change the *id* pattern like opt_1, opt_2 etc
  $('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo('#opt_' + id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easier than you think :)

```
<select id="select-1" onchange="Fill(2)"></select>
<select id="select-2" onchange="Fill(3)"></select>
<select id="select-3"></select>

function Fill(id){ // 
    //some manupulation
    $('<option/>').val(substr[0]).html(substr[1]).appendTo('select-' + id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the top of Fill function:

```
 var DYNAMIC = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with David Thomas' suggestion:

```
<select id="one" onchange="Fill(this);"></select>
<select id="two" onchange="Fill(this);"></select>
<select id="three"></select>
```

With the Fill function defined as:

```
function Fill(select) {
    $('<option />').val(/*..*/).html(/*..*/).appendTo($(select));
}
```

You would then be able to give your selects whatever id that you want, and you would not have to query the DOM to find the object.